# Add weapons to inventory

Tags: java, class, interface

I am trying to add weapons to a player inventory.  It's kind of hard to explain, so I'll try my best.  What I have are a class for each weapon, a class for Combat, and a class for the Player.  I am trying to get it to where when the Random number equals a certain number, it will add a weapon to the player inventory.  I will put my code Below.

Combat Class:

```
public class Combat {

M4 m4 = new M4();
M16 m16 = new M16();
M9 m9 = new M9();
Glock glock = new Glock();
SCAR Scar = new SCAR();

Player player = new Player();
final int chanceOfDrop = 3;


static boolean[] hasWeapon = {false, true};



public static int  ranNumberGen(int chanceOfDrop) {
    return (int) (Math.random()*5); 
}

private void enemyDead() {
    boolean canDrop = false;
    if(ranNumberGen(chanceOfDrop)==0){
        canDrop = true;

    }

    if(canDrop == true){

        if(ranNumberGen(0) == 1) {


            Player.addInvetory(m4.weaponName(wepName), m4.weaponAmmo(wepAmmo)); //Issues here.  wepName & wepAmmo cannot be resolved into variable
            //Should I just delete the line?
            //Trying to get it to add the weapon M4 to the player inventory.  
            //Maybe use an ArrayList? If so I need a couple pointers on how to implement this.  
        }


    }
    }
}
```

M4 Class:

```
public class M4 implements Armory {
//Weapon classes are practically identical except for differences in the name wepDamage and wepAmmo.
public Integer weaponAmmo(int wepAmmo) {
    wepAmmo = 10;
    return wepAmmo;
}

public Integer weaponDamage(int wepDamage) {
    wepDamage = 5;
    return wepDamage;
}

public String weaponName(String wepName) {
    wepName = "M4";
    return wepName;
}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player {
public static int health = 100;

//Player Class.

public static void addInvetory(String wepName, int wepAmmo) {

    Player.addInvetory(wepName, wepAmmo);
}

public static void removeInventory(String wepName, int wepAmmo) {

    Player.addInvetory(wepName, wepAmmo);
}


public static void removeAll(String wepName, int wepAmmo) {
    Player.removeAll(wepName, wepAmmo);
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface Armory {

//Interface implemented by all of the weapons classes.
public Integer weaponAmmo(int wepAmmo);
public Integer weaponDamage(int wepDamage);
public String weaponName(String wepName);
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: I didn't find question here

Comment: Why dont you just have one Weapon Class that has a Name property, why do you have to have a class per weapon?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what method arguments are for, and how they are passed. All the methods of M4 shouldn't take any argument. Same for `ranNumberGen()`. And you could probably use a single class to represent all the kinds of Armories. I suggest you go back to your introductory Java book or tutorial.

Comment: @MattiasJosefsson How would I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 class Weapon {
     private final String name;
     private final int damage;
     private final int ammo;
     public Weapon(final String name,final  int damage,final  int ammo) {
         this.name = name;
         this.damage = damage;
         this.ammo = ammo;
     }
     public Weapon clone() {
         return new Weapon(this.name,this.damage,this.ammo);
     }
     public String getName() {
         return this.name;
     }
     public int getAmmo() {
         return this.ammo;
     }
     public int getDamage() {
         return this.damage;
     }
 }

 class WeaponFactory {
      static WeaponFactory factory;
      public static WeaponFactory getWeaponFactory() {
           if(factory == null) {
               factory = new WeaponFactory();
           }
           return factory;
      }
      private ArrayList<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<Weapon>();
      private Random random;
      private WeaponFactory() {
           //TODO: Fix Ammo and Damage
           weapons.add(new Weapon("M4",0,0));
           weapons.add(new Weapon("M16",0,0));
           weapons.add(new Weapon("M9",0,0));
           weapons.add(new Weapon("Glock",0,0));
           weapons.add(new Weapon("SCAR",0,0));
      }
      public Weapon getWeapon() {
          int w = random.nextInt(weapons.length);
          return weapons.get(w).clone();
      }
 }

 class Combat {
      ...
      private void enemyDead() {
           if(ranNumberGen(chanceOfDrop)==0){
                 Player.addInventory(WeaponFactory.getWeaponFactory().getWeapon());
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of `Armory` and the generate a random number from 0 to the size of the array as an index to the array to decide which weapon to add.

Answer (score 0):

Okay dude, since your question about creating a programming language was closed, I'm answering it through here:

I think that your idea is great! Don't give up on it, yet don't get too excited. I would try all the options that you have heard of(interpreted route AND the Compiled route). If you can get either of those to work, then you may proceed to go into further detail with the language creation. It's going to take a while though. Be patient!